# Close Window (Xcodes "Installation Alert") that has no kind of closing elements

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there a tool with which I can click on a window and the tool will tell me which process that window belongs to ?

**Explanation:**

I was working in Xcode 3.2.3 for iPhone OS 4.0beta3.
Wanted to install old Xcode (all old SDKs got removed with beta3).

Didn't want to waste time so I kept working in new Xcode for iPhone OS 4.0beta3 while downloading and then starting the installation of xcode 3.2.2 with iPhone SDK 3.2.

After sometime there came this window:

"Installation Alert"

```
In order to continue installation, please close the following application:
Xcode
```

But by then I didn't want to interrupt my programming session as I was near a next milestone.
Well, next day and after a Macbook standby I finally wanted to close the Xcode with SDK 4beta3 and finally install the old SDK.
But the Installation Alert wouldn't disappear (even though Xcode was closed now). So I thought ok, then lets just stop and restart the Xcode Installation... So I went to the "Activity Monitor" and stopped the Xcode Installation. The Xcode Installation window got closed, but the "Installation Alert" is still there.

So how do you get rid of such a window ?
It has no buttons, no menu in which to select a "close window".

Edit:
Well a restart of course solves this problem. And I never faced this problem again.

Comment: This really belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Cool thanks, didn't know that page. Seems good

Comment: Is there a link to this question there?  I just hit the same problem with XCode 3.2.5.  If it wasn't copied, I can copy it (did a quick search and didn't find it, but still wary of creating dupes)

Comment: I just looked and realized that I never wrote the answer to superuser.com. This only happened once (though many many times I have uninstalled and installed new XCodes) and a restart "fixed" the problem, so that I lost my interest in an answer. Maybe you want to post this question at superuser.com.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

He's right. Kill 'AlertAll' and that will allow you to proceed. Make sure iTunes is also killed.

Comment: For the installation of Xcode 4.1, I also had to go into Terminal and kill the iTunesHelper process. Killing iTunes alone wasn't enough.

Comment: killing the AlertAll process did the trick for me when I ran into a similar problem installing Xcode on Lion.

Answer (score 26):

Killing the ItunesHelper is the solution.

For those who don't remember how to do that:

1. Go to Utilities
2. Open Activity Monitor
3. Find the ItunesHelper in the list of running processes.
4. Click on the "Quit process" button on the upper left corner of the window.

Comment: I would say that this is the correct solution (kill the program that makes the alert to be dismissed), rather than the accepted one (kill the program that produces the alert, which doesn't make Xcode 4.1 installation to continue as the iTunesHelper process is still running).

Answer (score 2):

"Same here... I am trying to install a 2gb xcode but that stupid window won't close>>> ANgRy"

Killing the iTunesHelper process worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me with Xcode 4.1 on Lion 10.7.0:

killall iTunesHelper

The installation resumed after that.
Fortunately I did not have to kill the messenger, AlertAll.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to kill "alert" process, via Activity Monitor or Terminal with killall command (after quitting iTunes of course).
Quide annoying bug indeed but hey - I'm not gonna reboot and reinstall all of these 4GB just because of a stupid window :)

Answer (score 1):

It’s now called “AlertAll,” and killing it no longer lets the installation continue. Best just to force quit XCode’s Installer instance (right or option-click on Installer icon, choose Force Quit), and then re-begin installation, making sure iTunes is shutdown first.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, turns out another user was logged onto the OS with iTunes open and once I closed that instance the message went away and the installation finished.

Answer (score 0):

When I killed the "AlertAll" process, the install finished, but Xcode would NOT launch.  I killed the iTunes Helper process and the alert window closed and install finished correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that you just have to reinstall it. Just turn off your computer and turn it back on and thats it! Simple as that! ;)

Comment: reinstalling and rebooting are two completely different things